# Block UI from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to block UI from external javascript file. 
With using jquery or without it how can i achieve this task.

Example:

this function contain in extranl javascript file.On call savedMessage i want to block ui and on click OK button unblock ui.since i made custom alert.

```
function savedMessage(message) {
    $("<div></div>").dialog({
        title: 'Skill Management System',
        resizable: false,
        width: 350,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).html('<img src="Images/info_icon.jpg"/><b>'+message+'</b>');
}
```

Comment: What would you do this?! What you mean?

Comment: Can you please explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `modal: true`

Try this:

```
function savedMessage(message) {
    $("<div></div>").dialog({
        title: 'Skill Management System',
        resizable: false,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).html('<img src="Images/info_icon.jpg"/><b>'+message+'</b>');
}
```

Check this **[link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)**

Answer (score 0):

You can download plugin forn
[Block UI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

and use $.blockUI(); to block UI